# How to test rest api written in codeigniter using URL manually

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest

How can I test my rest api via URL?

I copied code from https://github.com/alexmarton/RControl and it only have instruction for get method.

So far what I've tried are :

- http://test/api/blog/delete/2?format=json&X-API-KEY=1234
- http://test/api/delete/2?format=json&X-API-KEY=1234

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test your APIs with manual data.